# What to do with gigantic gdb directory, looking for smaller GeoJSONs

Tags: gdal, geojson

I was given a large .gdb directory containing all parcels for an entire state. I tried converting the entire thing using `ogr2ogr` using `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON TEST.json FOO.gdb`, but the resulting GeoJSON file was 35.5GB, then the process died with `Terminating translation prematurely after failed`.

Is there a notion of `decomposing` a `.gdb` file into smaller files, so that I may try to convert them into parcels in GeoJSON format, say per parcel, or per town maybe?

Comment: Yes, there's clip, sql, spat, and select facilities: http://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

Comment: ArcMap or QGIS could break it up into towns but you might script this up as there are ~2,500 municipalities, in PA, 410 in Mass, etc..Since Towns can have a few thousand parcels, the parcel level export would generate to many files. If it's possible put it in a spatial Enterprise Database like PostGIS and serve it as GeoJSON, Just filter on Town..

Answer (score 1):

Convert to GPKG first which is a SQLite database format with BLOB field for Geometry. 
Then Clip to an area of interest you need for the GeoJSON.
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" -clipsrc clipping_polygon.shp output.geojson input.gpkg
or by Bounding Box ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" output.geojson input.gpkg -clipsrc

also I use -lco RFC7946=YES
this reduces decimal places (default is 15) and makes it more mapbox/web friendly geojson.